# Conduct the calculation only when the value is not null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `dft`:

```
Date              Total Value
02/01/2022          2
03/01/2022          6 
03/08/2022          4
03/11/2022          
03/15/2022          4
05/01/2022          4
```

I want to calculate the total value in March, I used the following code:

```
Mar22 = dft.loc[dft['Date'].between('03/01/2022', '03/31/2022', inclusive='both'),'Total Value'].sum()
```

03/11/2022 has a null value, which caused an error. What should I add to my code so that I only sum the values that are not null?

Comment: what is the exact error, and what is the output of `list(dft['Total Value'])`?

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: But if I add a value in that data frame, the error will disappear

Comment: The output of  `list(dft['Total Value'])`:
['',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 ''
...]

Comment: df.fillna(0) convert NAN -> 0 then add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that you have an empty string (it should rather be a NaN).

You can ensure having only numbers with [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
out = (pd.to_numeric(df['Total Value'], errors='coerce')[dft['Date']
         .between('03/01/2022', '03/31/2022', inclusive='both')].sum()
      )
```

Or if you only have empty strings as non numeric values:

```
out = (dft.loc[dft['Date'].between('03/01/2022', '03/31/2022', inclusive='both'), 'Total Value']
          .replace('', float('nan')).sum()
       )
```

output: `14.0`

Answer (score 1):

Try the `pandas` built-in `notnull()` function.

```
Mar22 = dft.loc[dft['Total Value'].notnull()].loc[dft['Date'].between('03/01/2022', '03/31/2022', inclusive='both'),'Total Value'].sum()
```

Comment: this won't work, you're converting to boolean, thus having no useful data left for your operations

Comment: this is however too bad to use twice `notnull` ;)